# Is it possible to get to source of pivot table through Power BI?

Tags: pivot-table, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to get to source of pivot table through Power BI?

We have pivot table in Excel file connected to external source. 
We do not have access to the external source.
If we double click on the sum of sums in pivot table, we can show details of all data that the pivot table is built on. 
We would like to connect from Power BI to that detailed data on which the pivot is built on directly without intermediate step of clicking on sum of sums and saving the file. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to copy the source directly from the **Advance Editor** in Power Query then in Power BI create a Blank Query where you can paste the lines.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Brilliantly presented. It doesn't work in my case. When I expand queries and connections in Excel open query Properties (to see connection string for example) - it does not open in query editor like in your case.

Comment: Where is your source from? I found this https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/analyze-in-excel-from-power-bi-publisher-july-update/